# How can I give a user remote access to their home directory via putty without adding them to the sudo group

Tags: user-accounts, ubuntu-18.04

I created a user on an Ubuntu 18.04 server with the aim of giving the user password authentication access. They are a member of the users group. I added the user's name after my name to this line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
AllowUsers my_name their_name
```

I re-started the ssh server:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

but when I try to log in from Putty with the new user's name I get "access denied" and, of course, Putty locks up for a while. I'm not sure how long, but it gets longer each time I receive the access denied error, so this is a very time-consuming problem.

I get the same problem of access denied with FileZilla when attempting to log in as the new user to do basic SFTP.

What do I have to do give a user only the privileges they need to have access to their own home folder via Putty or FileZilla without giving them root privileges or making them part of the sudo group?

Comment: Does the user have their own home directory? in some cases it doesn't exist when you create a user (such as, for e.g., in some domain or LDAP scenarios I've seen) so maybe thats the issue.

Comment: I used Webmin to add the user and a home directory was created automatically.

Comment: Ah,ok. I'm guessing then that the permissions were granted to them automatically? It might be worth checking with "ls -al" to see if they own their own home directories. I don't know anything about Webmin so this is my only suggestion on the matter.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the new user owns their own home directory.